# Drupal: Read more in WYSIWYG

Tags: drupal, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Does some module exist for CKEditor (Drupal 7) similar to "read more" in Wordpress?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Go to a CKEditor Profile. example.com/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Advanced

Expand "Editor Appearance" scroll down to "Plugins" there should be a checkbox for "Plugin for inserting Drupal teaser and page breaks."  Then scroll up and you will see a button with a little red dotted line.  Drag that up to your "Current Toolbar"